# OCaml: List that could contain two types?

Tags: list, types, ocaml

Instead of specifying a int list or string list, could I specify a list whose members must be either strings or ints, but nothing else?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could do:

```
type element = IntElement of int | StringElement of string;;
```

and then use a list of `element`s.

Answer (score 7):

One option is [polymorphic variants](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/manual006.html#toc36). You can define the type of the list using:

```
# type mylist = [`I of int | `S of string] list ;;
type mylist = [ `I of int | `S of string ] list
```

Then define values such as:

```
# let r : mylist = [`I 10; `S "hello"; `I 0; `S "world"] ;;
val r : mylist = [`I 10; `S "hello"; `I 0; `S "world"]
```

You have to be careful to add type annotations, though, because polymorphic variants are "open" types. E.g., the following is legal:

```
# let s = [`I 0; `S "foo"; `B true]
val s : [> `B of bool | `I of int | `S of string ] list =
  [`I 0; `S "foo"; `B true]
```

To prevent the type of a list from allowing non-integer-or-string values, use an annotation:

```
# let s : mylist = [`I 0; `S "foo"; `B true];;
This expression has type [> `B of bool ] but is here used with type
  [ `I of int | `S of string ]
The second variant type does not allow tag(s) `B
```